# "Only a ReactOwner can have refs" despite running a single react copy and no broken refs

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack

I'm getting the good old

`invariant.js:44 Uncaught Error: addComponentAsRefTo(...): Only a ReactOwner     can have refs. You might be adding a ref to a component that was not created inside a component's render method, or you have multiple copies of React loaded`

The refs are definitely not the problem (they are in the render method, and the issue persists after they're removed). I also don't have multiple copies of react  - there is not a single additional copy in node_modules, npm ls react returns a single instance, I have no react plugins installed. I'm using webpack.

adding aliases in webpack config didn't help, reinstalling dependencies didn't help, removing react and linking it from outside npm/webpack didn't help.

here's my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    watch: true,
    entry: "./components/FreshInvestigationForm/FreshInvestigationForm.tsx",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: __dirname + "/dist"
    },
    devtool: "source-map",    
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json", "css"]
    },    
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts|\.tsx$/,
                use: ["babel-loader","awesome-typescript-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.css?$/,
                use: ["css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
                use: 'file-loader?name=public/fonts/[name].[ext]'
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
                use: ['file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=[hash].[ext]',
                    'image-webpack-loader?bypassOnDebug&optimizationLevel=7&interlaced=false']
            },
            {
                enforce: "pre",
                test: /\.js$|\.jsx$/,
                use: ["babel-loader", "source-map-loader"]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

and my dependencies

```
 "dependencies": {
    "@types/react": "15.0.30",
    "@types/react-dom": "^15.5.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "^3.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "source-map": "^0.5.6",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.2",
    "typescript": "^2.4.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.4.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.22.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.23.0",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.2",
    "image-webpack-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "typescript-simple-loader": "^0.3.8",
    "webpack": "^3.3.0"
  }
```

also, what a horrible error, pretty much everyone who solved it did it in a different way.

EDIT:

I've managed to narrow the problem down somewhat, there are several components that trigger the error but I can't identify the problem. All of them are called in the same place like this:

```
listToRender.forEach((item: field, index: number) => {
            const subGroup: Object = item.hasOwnProperty("subGroup") ? item.subGroup : null;
            const isDropdown = this.state.dropdowns[item.value] !== undefined;
            const isSearchDropdown = this.state.searchDropdowns.indexOf(item.value) > -1;
            const isMultiYear = this.state.multiYear.indexOf(item.value) > -1;
            const isMultipleSelection = this.state.multipleSelectionDropdowns.indexOf(item.value) > -1;
             if (isSearchDropdown) {
                listElems.push(<SearchSelectFormElem /> }
else {and so on for other possibilities}
return(<ul>{listToRender}</ul>)
```

this is the shortest one of the offending components. Don't be misled by it having a ref, removing it changes nothing

```
import * as React from "react";
var $: any = $;

export interface IProps {
    givenId: string;
    specialType: string;
    inputValue?: string;
    updateModel: Function;
}

export default class SearchSelectFormElem extends React.Component<IProps, { selectNode: any }> {
    private searchSelect: HTMLSelectElement;
    showDropdown() {
        $(this.searchSelect).select2("open");
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        $(this.searchSelect).select2({ selec2 options });
    }
    render() {
        let fieldLabel: string = this.props.givenId;
        fieldLabel = fieldLabel.replace(/([A-Z])/g, ' $1').trim();

        return (
            <li className="form-list-elem has-special-input dropdown">
                <label htmlFor={this.props.givenId} className="form-label">
                    {fieldLabel}
                </label>
                <div className="special-wrapper">
                    <select ref={(node) => {this.searchSelect = node}} className="form-input main-form-input select2picker search-dropdown" id={this.props.givenId}>
                        <option>{this.props.inputValue}</option>
                    </select>
                    <span className="special-control dropdown" onClick={this.showDropdown.bind(this)}></span>
                </div>
            </li>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried looking at `npm ls`. Maybe a global and local copy of different versions?

Comment: yes, I have. I found nothing, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I've written before, the error is horrible and the error message is unhelpful.

The actual reason was jquery (the project is being migrated to react but relies on some jquery plugins). Despite working properly, react would only allow it to be called through an import. Once I started calling it like this

```
import * as $ from 'jquery'
```

the app started working again.